# Volver a una pestaña de una página anterior

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

He estado trabajando para una página web en una página de aterrizaje que contiene varias pestañas, y estas pestañas vinculan a diferentes productos.
Quiero que al presionar "atras" el navegador me devuelva a la página de aterrizaje pero con la última pestaña que utilice abierta

```html
        <div class="col-sm-3 lefttab-content">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs2 nav-stacked ">
            <li class="active" id="title1"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-one" href="#ids">Industrial Switches</a></li>
            <li id="title2"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-two" href="#fibermc">Fiber Media Converters</a></li>
            <li id="title3"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-three" href="#serialtoe">Serial to Ethernet</a></li>
            <li id="title4"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-four" href="#serialex">Serial Extenders</a></li>
            <li id="title5"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-five" href="#ethernetex">Ethernet Extenders</a></li>
            <li id="title6"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-six" href="#poe">Power Over Ethernet</a></li>
            <li id="title7"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-seven" href="#surgepro">Surge Protectors</a></li>
            <li id="title8"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-eight" href="#pcicard">PCI Cards</a></li>
            <li id="title9"><a data-toggle="tab" id="tab-nine" href="#acc">Accessories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
         <div class="tab-content tab-content2 col-sm-9">
          <div id="ids" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <div class="row"><a class="no-underline" href="#un link relativo#">
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2>Industrial Ethernet Switches</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3">
                <p><img src="/productimages/ids-montage-sm.jpg" alt="Industrial Ethernet Switches" width="100" height="97" class="img-center img-responsive h100"></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-9"><br>
                <p>5, 7, 8 or 10 port Industrial DIN Rail Ethernet Switches.  Fast Ethernet or Gigabit.  Optional fiber ports with ST, SC or SFP connectors.  PoE/PoE+ PSE capable models that are fully compliant to IEEE 802.3af/at</p>
              </div>
              </a> </div>
```

Comment: Suena a guardar en una variable la última pestaña a la que se le hizo click y usar la liga como referencia para regresar la pestaña, pero ¿Qué es lo que has intentado hacer para resolver el problema?

Comment: Podría recurrir a `window.history.back();`

Comment: Bueno basicamente he jugado con los id y classes porque nadie aqui en la oficina sabe hacerlo jaja entonces estoy investigando, gracias leere un poco lo de window.history.back (); porque nada mas de leer me parece que tiene sentido

Comment: @AnthonyJohnRamirezLlanos cuéntenos sí funciono la recomendación o busca otra solución.

Comment: en efecto @Dev.Joel gracias por tu aporte!!! mil gracias de verdad

Comment: @AnthonyJohnRamirezLlanos añadí la respuesta para que la pregunta no quede abierta y sin respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Añadiré esta respuesta para que la pregunta no quede abierta*

Para volver a la página anterior del navegador en una pestaña puede emplear `window.history.back();` que básicamente hace lo mismo que dar atrás en el navegador , es decir recurre al historial del navegador. Puede emplear cualquiera de estos dos métodos.

```
window.history.go(-1);
window.history.back();
```

> Nota: Este método no funcionará si la página anterior no existe en la
>   lista del historial.

Comment: es perfecto porque precisamente la idea es que venga desde esa pagina! buen trabajo!